# Can you use parametrized PDO to add columns AND values?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have the following code which works, but it's not using `PDO` which is what I normally use:

```
<?php
    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' ) {

        // will go all the way upto 50
        $fields = array('db_field1'=>'cb1', 'dbfield2'=>'cb2', 'dbfield3'=>'cb3', 'dbfield4'=>'cb4');

        $update = '';

        foreach($fields as $dbfield => $field) {
            if ($update) $update.= ',';

            $update.= ' '.$dbfield.'=';

            if (isset($_POST[$field])) {
                $update.= 1;
            } else {
                $update.= 0;
            }
        }

        // show generated query
        echo 'UDPATE table SET'.$update.' WHERE 1=1';
    }
?>

<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <form method="post">
            <input type="checkbox" name="cb1" />
            <input type="checkbox" name="cb2" />
            <input type="checkbox" name="cb3" />
            <input type="checkbox" name="cb4" />
            <!-- all the way to 50 -->

            <input type="submit" value="submit" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Because I am getting the `column names` AND the `column values` to be updated from the code above, I am not sure how to do this using `PDO`?

I have done the following code below:

```
<?php
    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' ) {

        $fields = array('db_field1'=>'cb1', 'dbfield2'=>'cb2', 'dbfield3'=>'cb3', 'dbfield4'=>'cb4');

        $update = '';

        foreach($fields as $dbfield => $field) {
            if ($update) $update.= ',';

            $update.= ' '.$dbfield.'=';

            if (isset($_POST[$field])) {
                $update.= 1;
            } else {
                $update.= 0;
            }
        }

        $DBH = new PDO( "mysql:host=localhost;dbname=database", "user", "pass" );
        $DBH -> setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );

        $STH = $DBH -> prepare( "update table1 set :update where id = :id" );

        $STH -> bindParam( ':update', $update, PDO::PARAM_STR, 255 );
        $STH -> bindParam( ':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT, 4 );

        $STH -> execute();
    }
?>

<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <form method="post">
            <input type="checkbox" name="cb1" />
            <input type="checkbox" name="cb2" />
            <input type="checkbox" name="cb3" />
            <input type="checkbox" name="cb4" />
            <!-- all the way to 50 -->

            <input type="submit" value="submit" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

But it gives me the following error:

> [Tue Jul 19 09:15:44 2011] [error] [client ::1] PHP Fatal error: 
>   Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]:
>   Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL
>   syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version
>   for the right syntax to use near '' db_field1=0, dbfield2=1,
>   dbfield3=1, dbfield4=0' where id = 1' at line 1' in
>   /var/www/page1.php:30\nStack trace:\n#0
>   /var/www/page1.php(30): PDOStatement->execute()\n#1
>   {main}\n  thrown in /var/www/page1.php on line 30,
>   referer: http:// localhost/page1.php

Comment: Try it and post your results?

Comment: I have tried it.  Please see the error I get.

Comment: So debug it, it's a syntax error. Output your query, find your error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
$DBH = new PDO( "mysql:host=localhost;dbname=database", "user", "pass" );
$DBH -> setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );

$STH = $DBH -> prepare( "update table1 set " . $update . " where id = :id" );

//$STH -> bindParam( ':update', $update, PDO::PARAM_STR, 255 );
$STH -> bindParam( ':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT, 4 );

$STH -> execute();
```

instead of:

```
$DBH = new PDO( "mysql:host=localhost;dbname=database", "user", "pass" );
$DBH -> setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );

$STH = $DBH -> prepare( "update table1 set :update where id = :id" );

$STH -> bindParam( ':update', $update, PDO::PARAM_STR, 255 );
$STH -> bindParam( ':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT, 4 );

$STH -> execute();
```

Or you can use this:

```
if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' ) { 
    $fields = array('db_field1'=>'cb1', 'dbfield2'=>'cb2', 'dbfield3'=>'cb3', 'dbfield4'=>'cb4');

    $update = array();
    $values = array();

    foreach($fields as $dbfield => $field) {
        $update[] = $dbfield . " = ? ";
        $values[] = isset($_POST[$field]) ? 1 : 0;
    }

    $values[] = $id;

    $DBH = new PDO( "mysql:host=localhost;dbname=database", "user", "pass" );
    $DBH->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );

    $STH = $DBH->prepare( "update table1 set " . join( ',', $update ) . " where id = ?" );

    $STH->execute($values);
}
```

instead of:

```
if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' ) { 
    $fields = array('db_field1'=>'cb1', 'dbfield2'=>'cb2', 'dbfield3'=>'cb3', 'dbfield4'=>'cb4');

    $update = '';

    foreach($fields as $dbfield => $field) {
        if ($update) $update.= ',';

        $update.= ' '.$dbfield.'=';

        if (isset($_POST[$field])) {
            $update.= 1;
        } else {
            $update.= 0;
        }
    }

    $DBH = new PDO( "mysql:host=localhost;dbname=database", "user", "pass" );
    $DBH -> setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );

    $STH = $DBH -> prepare( "update table1 set :update where id = :id" );

    $STH -> bindParam( ':update', $update, PDO::PARAM_STR, 255 );
    $STH -> bindParam( ':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT, 4 );

    $STH -> execute();
}
```

Comment: Doesn't this defeat the whole objective of using PDO?

Comment: No, it doesn't. I will add one more variation of what you could do.